# With django, how to control the server's stop and start again by batch.bat via a button on the screen, use the Windows operating system

Tags: django, powershell, shell, batch-file, django-views

**With django, how to control the server's stop and start again by batch.bat via a button on the screen, use the Windows operating system**

all the methods I got The process is done manually and I didn't find an automated way or code that works on it
for example:
1-I have to Open Windows PowerShell as Administrator
Find PID (ProcessID) for port 8080:

```
netstat -aon | findstr 8000

TCP 0.0.0.0:8080 0.0.0.0:0 LISTEN 77777
```

Kill the zombie process:

```
taskkill /f /pid 77777
```

**Now we return to the question**

how can I do this process automatically, either through the batch.bat file or through the django code

Comment: Run your `NETSTAT.EXE` command within a batch file using a `FOR /F` loop, `For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\NETSTAT.EXE -aon ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe ":8000 "') Do For %%H In (%%G) Do Set "PID=%%H"` which should capture the Process ID as a variable. Then you can use `%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /PID %PID% /T` to terminate that process, _(and any of its child processes)_. _Please do not use the `/F` option with TaskKill to forcefully close the process, that should only be used when allowing it to close gracefully has already failed._

Comment: thank you 
@ECHO OFF                                                                              
FOR /F "tokens=5" %%T IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr "8000" ') DO (
SET /A ProcessId=%%T) &GOTO SkipLine                                                   
:SkipLine                                                                              
echo ProcessId to kill = %ProcessId%
taskkill /f /pid %ProcessId%
PAUSE

I used the batch file and called it via Python as you said and it worked
call file batch
import os
os.system(r"D:\close.bat")

Comment: I would advise that you do not use `Tokens=5`, but to use the code I provided. Often the results may not have data in all of the 'columns' of the returned tabular formatted output , which means that your PID may not always be the fifth token. That is why I used a standard loop to capture only the last column item. I also correctly used the full paths and extensions for your executables, gave you a better string match command using a different executable, told you not to use TaskKill's `/F` option, and advised that you also include the `/T` option. There is no need to use `Set`'s `/A` option…

Comment: …by all means act like you know better, but remember that you were the one asking for help, and I believe that my solution is more suitable, considerably more robust and kinder to your system!